# How do I do a traversal like DFS in a DAG on an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but I'm not sure what the graph traversal I need is called, so I'm having difficulty finding any information about it.

I have an undirected, biconnected graph.  If I choose a vertex with two or more edges, I would like to compute a property that's accumulated around all paths from the vertex back to itself.  I'm not sure what sort of traversal I need, however, to traverse the loop in one direction.

It seems to me that the the traversal I want is equivalent to cutting one of the two edges on the vertex I'm interested in, assigning a direction to all of the other edges such that they point away from the remaining edge (and toward the edge I cut), and then doing a DFS.  I could do exactly that, but I'm not sure how to assign the direction of the edges.  I was thinking that I could use Dijkstra's algorithm to compute distances to the cut point and use that as a way of assigning direction, but that doesn't sound like it would be sufficient.

Is there a name for this sort of traversal, or is there anywhere I could read up on it?

Comment: Without more information on the information you want to accumulate, it's impossible to tell, but what you describe (message passing algorithm in DAG generalized to general graphs) looks a lot like a problem solved by computing a tree decomposition, then using dynamic programming. This ensure an efficient algorithm if the treewidth of the graph is small.